# Is this deduction in normal form?

Tags: proof-theory, natural-deduction

**Definition**: A deduction is in normal form if there is no formula which is a conclusion of an introduction rule and the main premise of the elimination rule of the same connective.

So, in a natural deduction system, one can normalize a proof that contains an introduction rule of a connective followed right after by the elimination rule of the same connective. Here, I have the opposite. First two elimination rules and then the introduction rule of the same connective.

[image: deduction]

By this definition, the above deduction is in normal form. But still, it can be reduced to a simpler deduction (the trivial A∧B). It seems correct to me, that we can reduce it to just the axiom $A\wedge B$. But how, since the structure of the deduction doesn't have a pair of rules that could be eliminated?

For whoever cannot see the image on the post, I'll give a description of the deduction depicted in it.

(1): $A\wedge B\vdash A$ (by conjunction elimination)

(2): $A\wedge B\vdash B$ (by conjunction elimination, again)

(3): $A, B\vdash A\wedge B$ (by conjunction introduction on (1) and (2))

Comment: I'm not able to read the link. It is much easier for the "potential answerers" if you type in the formulas.

Comment: You can download [Latex symbols](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf‎) from the web for the symbols, used the tutorial of this site and last (without saving) edit a question/answer with the formula you need and copy them ...

Comment: For the tutorial of this site, see the [guideline](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117)

Comment: I think that (3) is wrong; it must be like : $A, B \vdash A \land B$. If your tree is made by two branch: the first one ending with (1) and the second one with (2), and after them you use again (with $A$ and $B$ as premisses) $\land$-I, why you need it ? Of course, we must see what we have on top of (1) and (2), but if what you need is *really* $A \land B$ and you have already on branch (1), I think you can use that only...

Comment: Now I read it - simply "cut" the right branch (for example) and avoid the "detour" from $A \land B$ to $A \land B$ through $A$.

Comment: What is your definition of "normal form"?

Comment: A deduction is in normal form if there is no formula which is a conclusion of an introduction rule and the main premise of the elimination rule of the same connective. By this definition, the above deduction **is** in normal form. But still, it can be reduced to a simpler deduction (the trivial $A\wedge B$). Anyway, the answer is in the $\eta$-reductions in λ-calculus and the Curry-Howard isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Curry-Howard isomorphism, the deduction in question corresponds exactly to an $\eta$-reduction of $\lambda$-calculus.

Unfortunately, the books for proof theory that I have, don't mention this class of reduction rules.